# Letter of Sponsorship from my father

Tags: uk, tourist-visas, applications

I'm applying for a UK visit visa as a single employed girl in Pakistan. My father is going to be sponsoring my visit. Is it going to be of any benefit if he explains in his **Letter of Support** that he has previously sponsored a trip for my mother and sister to the UK and that they returned as scheduled? And also that he sponsored a trip to Turkey for the entire family?

Answer (score 1):

Your father should explain why he is sponsoring you (eg because he has previously sponsored other family members and wishes to do the same for you) but having a sponsor does not remove the need for you to qualify for a visa in your own right. See under ‘Sponsorship Issues’ in [UK visa refusal on V 4.2 a + c (and sometimes 'e')](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e)

Comment: Addition for the OP: Treating family members equal is a probably a good reason to mention having previously mother and sister, but the fact that they returned doesn't mean much whether assessing if you will, and as @Traveller writes you have to qualify yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm going to show my own bank statements too but the only problem with that is that its currently close to nil as i usually get a 75% of my salary out to purchase dollars in order to save money. However, i plan to credit money to the account again before applying. Do you think that will be looked at as 'funds parking' also? Even though my father is the sponsor and his bank statement should technically be the primary concern

Comment: @ayesha do you have documents that show you are buying dollars with your salary? Ideally a bank account in your name, in dollars? That would help.

Comment: @Ayesha Your own bank statements are the primary concern, not your sponsor’s, because they help to demonstrate your own personal circumstances https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab Without evidence to tie up your cash withdrawals with your $ purchases and to prove the source of other cash deposits into your account, the ECO may not be able to gain a sufficient level of understanding from your statements.

Comment: The major deposits in my account are my salary deposits which, subjectively speaking, is a pretty good amount for someone to be getting my age. I will attach pay slips and a letter from my employer. Looking at the consistency of these deposits, don't you think that the ECO will be satisfied with my personal circumstances? And the deposit close to my application (the one i will deposit after selling the dollars) is not going to be of much concern?

Comment: @Ayesha A regular salary will be a positive; a cash deposit from an unsubstantiated source close to your application will likely raise funds parking concerns and therefore be a negative.